# Caching to files (not memory) in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

Is there any simle way how to save objects to files in selected directory?

**I have:**

- **Object** (webservice response)
- **Id** (md5 hash)
- **Cache life time** (6 days)
- **Folder** (where to save files)

**I need:** some solution, where I can

- set **cache directory**
- set **hierarchical directory level** (all files cannot be in one directory, there can be thousands of files)
- **add** (rewrite expired file) / **get** object to / from cache
- **thread safety**

Answer (score 3):

.Net has the ability to create custom cache providers.

I have seen articles on how to create a disk based one.

here is a link on creating a mongodb based one. Dependent on your experience level that may be enough to see you through.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

I'll see if I can find the article about the disk based one.

found it https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121627/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061610-1.aspx